# SD_CARD formatting to ext4

Tags: android, filesystems, flash-memory, soc

I have been working on gaming application. I am trying to load the image on flash memory of board. For this i am using sdcard and from sdcard i am writing the image into flash memory of board. Before writing into flash the sdcard format is FAT. But after writing into flash and loading the image, the sdcard content format changes to EXT4. I have tried with different sdcard's.

This shows different behavior...and there is loss of content in sdcard due to this re-formatting.

Anyone's help is appreciated...

Comment: Can you please add your code?
I'm a bit confused, you're trying to **read** data from the sdcard or to **write** data to it?

Comment: Hi Eselfar thanks for your replay. I am copying the data from sdcard to flash using u-boot commands. Before copying sdcard format is FAT, but after copying it is formatted to ext4.